# What is the meaning of this?

Tags: c

hi guys can you explain what does that greater than sign do in the follwing code

```
 if (header->mode > forceMode)
      {
        *rate >>= (header->mode - forceMode); //What does this mean >>=
         *granule_frame_size <<= (header->mode - forceMode); //What does this mean <<=
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While all the answers above are correct, it's possible you might still not understand it. You will need to understand binary.

Imagine you have the expression

7 << 2

That means "Convert 7 into binary, then shift all the bits left 2 times."

So 7 is 00000111

shifted left twice (and inserting zeros) yeilds:

00011100

This is equal to 28.

So if the variable A is 7, and B is 2, then:

```
A <<= B;
```

Leaves A equal to 28;

Answer (score 2):

`>>=` is the right-shift assignment operator.  `x >>= y` is equivalent to `x = x >> y` (with the caveat that @bdonlan points out below).

Comment: Strictly speaking, `x >>= y` differs from `x = x >> y` in that `x` is evaluated only once (ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (E) §6.5.16.2.3)

Answer (score 2):

The `<<` and `>>` operators are traditionally thought of bitwise because that's how they're implemented, but as far as the C language is concerned, they are **arithmetic** operators (not bitwise operators) equivalent to multiplication and division by the corresponding power of 2. That is, `x<<y` is x*2^y and `x>>y` is x/2^y (with integer truncation), where by ^ I mean "raised to the power" and not "xor". They are only defined for positive values of `x`, and like all arithmetic operators, `<<` has undefined behavior for signed operands if the result overflows.